# Use C# Task Scheduler library to End Task

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm currently using this library for the windows task scheduler https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler

What I want is to end the running task. In my research, I found that I can able to disable the task by this code snippet `task.Definition.Settings.Enabled = false`. But I did not find any way to end the running task. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`task.Enabled = false` will disable the single task immediately. `task.Definition.Settings.Enabled = false` is used to disable a task before registration.

To terminate a running task, use:

`if (task.IsActive && task.State == TaskState.Running) task.Stop();`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
task.Stop();
```

https://dahall.github.io/TaskScheduler/html/M_Microsoft_Win32_TaskScheduler_Task_Stop.htm

You can retrieve all tasks using:

```
new TaskService().AllTasks
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are looking is `Task.Stop()` and `RunningTask.Stop()`(inherited from `Task` class) methods. Obviously, they stops the registered task immediately. As described in [source code](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/blob/de56c0be0bd44779375a1b5488226c09f376105a/TaskService/Task.cs#L1559):

> System account users can stop a task, users with Administrator group
> privileges can stop a task, and if a user has rights to execute and
> read a task, then the user can stop the task. A user can stop the task
> instances that are running under the same credentials as the user
> account. In all other cases, the user is denied access to stop the
> task.

Is that what you looking for?